# String from Data without copying

Tags: swift, string

I want to create a `String` from `Data` without copying. I've been trying to use 
`String(bytesNoCopy:UnsafeMutableRawPointer, length:Int, encoding:String.Encoding, freeWhenDone:Bool)`

No matter how I try it always returns nil. If I create it using `String(bytes:..., encoding:...)` it succeeds.

Is there a way to try create a `String` from the `Data` object without duplicating the bytes.

Here is where its coming from and what I've tried:

```
 ...
 // get the data. This succeeds
 guard var data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe) else {
        return .failed
 }

 //Tried: 
 let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&data)
 let str = String(bytesNoCopy: ptr, length: data.count, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this is actually currently not possible to do. While the other answer suggests the `bytesNoCopy` initializer for `String`, this was always a hint and misleadingly named, hence eventually being deprecated.

This thread describes the situation in more detail for people that are still interested in this: https://forums.swift.org/t/init-bytesnocopy-was-deprecated-in-macos-13/61231/4

Answer (score 1):

Going back through trying again I found a way that is working:

```
 ...
 // get the data. This succeeds
 guard var data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe) else {
        return .failed
 }


 data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
        let unsafePtr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(ptr)
        // This is now working
        let str = String(bytesNoCopy: unsafePtr, length: data.count, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false)
 }
```